# Workflow is still in active status

Tags: oracle, workflow

I create a workflow which has approval and reject notifications, upon approval, my workflow will perform some activity,but after approving the notification my workflow is not moving forward.

Comment: What tool are you using to build this workflow?

Answer (score 0):

May be he is using Oracle Workflow builder